# How to implement the PhoneGap Calendar Plugin

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Here is the Link: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin#phonegap-build

I am wrapping the application in android through PhoneGap Build, not locally. So I wanted to know if I only need to follow the "PhoneGap Build" section under the Installation guidelines? Or do I need to add additional steps. As of right now I added  `<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.calendar" />` to the config.xml file. And I added

```
<!-- below <script src="phonegap.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/plugins/Calendar.js"></script>
```

to the index.html file

Then created this function:

```
function save() {
      var startDate = new Date("September 24, 2014 13:00:00");
  var endDate = new Date("September 24, 2014 14:30:00");
  var title = "My nice event";
  var location = "Home";
  var notes = "Some notes about this event.";
  var success = function(message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
  var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + message); };


  // create (the only function also supported on Android for now)
  window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);

};
```

along with a button to call the above function onClick.

I feel like I am completely missing something, so if my errors come off as obviously please remember I am new to plugins and wrapping with PhoneGap. The PhoneGap build is 3.1 if you need to know. Thanks for any help!

Edit: Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.mobile.Build"
        versionCode=""
        version   = "1.0">
        <name>Build</name>
        <description>
        </description>
        <author href="www.removed.net" email="editor@removed">
SMD
        </author>
        <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
        <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
        <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
        <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
        <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
        <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
        <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
        <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
        <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
        <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
        <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
        <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
        <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
        <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
        <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
        <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
        <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
        <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
        <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
        <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
        <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
        <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
        <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
        <gap:platform name="android" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
        <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.calendar" />
        <access origin="*"/>
    </widget>
```

Comment: You should try removing `<script src="js/plugins/Calendar.js"></script>`. In PhoneGap 3.x+ you don't need to add anything other than the line in config.xml

Comment: No luck :/ any other suggestions?

Comment: can you add you config.xml to your question?

Comment: OK I added the config.xml

Comment: Hi Bacon2305, could you please share your final code? I'm having some hard time with this plugin... thanks!

Comment: Hey RickON, I ended up building locally. Couldn't get it to work with PhoneGap Build. Let me know if you are interested in that method and I can help you.